# Windows server on bare metal vs hyper-v regarding DPM 2010

Tags: scdpm, hyper-v-server-2016, bare-metal

Planning how to set up a newly purchased server. It is to be placed in my DMZ, hosting webapps only requiring a simple software stack of Java, Tomcat servlet container, and PostgreSQL database on top of Windows.

My plan is to either:

1. Bare metal installation of Windows Server 2016, or:
2. Hyper-V server 2016 and use the Windows Server 2016 license for a VM.

I do need to be able to restore the Windows 2016 Server in case of hardware failure, but I'm not sure which of the two options are better for this. I am currently using DPM 2010 to backup the VMs on another server running the Hyper-V, although as a Role (2008R2)

Here are my questions:

1. Can I install the DPM client on a Hyper-V Server 2016?
2. If hardware fails on the Hyper-V Server 2016 and I need to restore the VMs on a different physical server, is that easy / even possible using the DPM2010 backup?
3. Is it a better option to simply install Server 2016 Standard on bare metal and use DPM2010 to simply perform file backup from the server and let a restore process involve reinstalling server 2016 Standard on other hardware, install all necessary software and finally restore data files from DPM2010 onto the new server?

Comment: I don't know DPM2010 and my background is Linux, but VMs make backups/snapshots/migrations etc much easier. And a VM doesn't necessarily have to be (much) slower. I'd go for that option.

Comment: Halfgaar, I'm leaning towards that as well, but the community may have knowledge about DPM and Hyper-V Server (of which I have none regarding the latter) that could change my mind. Let's see what the experts say!

Comment: Windows Server 2016 is not supported with DPM 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. *Can I install the DPM client on a Hyper-V Server 2016?*  Alas, no, as Greg Askew points out above [2016 isn't one of the supported operating systems for DPM 2010](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff399234.aspx).
2. *If hardware fails on the Hyper-V Server 2016 and I need to restore the VMs on a different physical server, is that easy / even possible using the DPM2010 backup?* You would need to upgrade to a version of DPM that supports Windows Server 2016.  That said, [DPM supports restoring Hyper-V VMs to another server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/dpm/back-up-hyper-v-virtual-machines?view=sc-dpm-1801), and even without DPM you should be able to export/import, or move the VM some other way.  If you have advance warning you could also  [live migrate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/use-live-migration-without-failover-clustering-to-move-a-virtual-machine) to another server.
3. *Is it a better option to simply install Server 2016 Standard on bare metal and use DPM2010 to simply perform file backup from the server and let a restore process involve reinstalling server 2016 Standard on other hardware, install all necessary software and finally restore data files from DPM2010 onto the new server?*  Unfortunately, see above.

All of that said, my personal preference based on your description would be to use a VM for all the reasons Halfgaar gave in his comment, but upgrading DPM would be a prerequisite to backing up Windows server 2016 with DPM.

Comment: Katherine, thank you very much for your answer! Incompatability between legacy DPM2010 and Server 2016 - of course. Any hints towards an alternative backup solution than DPM if I did not go for SCCM 2016?

Comment: Not really (sorry!).  Any backup solution that you know and does what you need it to do is your best choice, in my opinion.